# Looping through objects in arrays to compare values

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays composed of objects. One array is made of restaurant objects with properties name and averagePrice. The other array is made of price objects (cheap, medium, expensive) with properties label, lowEnd, and highEnd. lowEnd and highEnd represent the thresholds that determine if the restaurant is cheap, medium, or expensive. I want to create a function that loops through the restaurants, and returns the restaurant whose average price lands within the given price range. I get an error that says:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: lowEnd)

I know that this is because I am not properly targeting the array object property of the price. Can someone help me figure out how to properly target an array object property? Thanks

Here is my code

```
    const priceArray = [
    cheap = {label: '$', lowEnd: 10, highEnd: 20},
    medium = {label: '$$', lowEnd: 21, highEnd: 30},
    expensive = {label: '$$$', lowEnd: 31, highEnd: 40},

];


const restaurants = [
    McDonalds = {name: 'Mcdonalds', averagePrice: 12},
    Sushi = {name: 'Sushi', averagePrice: 25},
    Steak = {name: 'Steak', averagePrice: 35}
];




function showRestaurants(price) {
    for (let restaurant of restaurants) {
    //if the average price is cheap, log that restaurant
            if (restaurant.averagePrice >= priceArray.price.lowEnd && restaurant.averagePrice < priceArray.price.highEnd)
                console.log(restaurant);
        }
};

showRestaurants(medium);
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the price array too.

Comment: I'd put the name of the price as a property like you are doing with "restaurants", then you can just iterate over "priceArray", like jarmod said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `priceArray.price` and `priceArray` is also an array with key names `cheap`, `medium`, and `expensive`

You've already passed `medium` as the data you want to check correctly, so I'd suggest you should use `price` param in `showRestaurants(price)` instead. In this case, it will consider `medium` as `price`

```
showRestaurants(medium);
```

The possible fix could be

- `priceArray.price.lowEnd` to `price.lowEnd`
- `priceArray.price.highEnd` to `price.highEnd`

```js
const priceArray = [
  cheap = {
    label: '$',
    lowEnd: 10,
    highEnd: 20
  },
  medium = {
    label: '$$',
    lowEnd: 21,
    highEnd: 30
  },
  expensive = {
    label: '$$$',
    lowEnd: 31,
    highEnd: 40
  },

];


const restaurants = [
  McDonalds = {
    name: 'Mcdonalds',
    averagePrice: 12
  },
  Sushi = {
    name: 'Sushi',
    averagePrice: 25
  },
  Steak = {
    name: 'Steak',
    averagePrice: 35
  }
];




function showRestaurants(price) {
  for (let restaurant of restaurants) {
    //if the average price is cheap, log that restaurant
    if (restaurant.averagePrice >= price.lowEnd && restaurant.averagePrice < price.highEnd)
      console.log(restaurant);
  }
};

showRestaurants(medium);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: very well done. I knew I didnt have to loop through the price array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
 const priceArray = [
    {label: '$', lowEnd: 10, highEnd: 20},
    {label: '$$', lowEnd: 21, highEnd: 30},
    {label: '$$$', lowEnd: 31, highEnd: 40},

];


const restaurants = [
     {name: 'Mcdonalds', averagePrice: 12},
   {name: 'Sushi', averagePrice: 25},
   {name: 'Steak', averagePrice: 35}
];

const withPriceLabel  =  restaurants.map(r => {
 return {
   ...r,
   priceEvaluation: priceArray.find(p => r.averagePrice >= p.lowEnd && r.averagePrice <= p.highEnd).label
 }
})

console.log(withPriceLabel.filter(r => r.priceEvaluation === '$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick. Here's a quick solution

```
const CHEAP = { label: "$", lowEnd: 10, highEnd: 20 };
const MEDIUM = { label: "$$", lowEnd: 21, highEnd: 30 };
const EXPENSIVE = { label: "$$$", lowEnd: 31, highEnd: 40 };

const priceArray = [CHEAP, MEDIUM, EXPENSIVE];

const McDonalds = { name: "Mcdonalds", averagePrice: 12 };
const Sushi = { name: "Sushi", averagePrice: 25 };
const Steak = { name: "Steak", averagePrice: 35 };

const restaurants = [McDonalds, Sushi, Steak];

function showRestaurants(price) {
  const filteredRestaurants = [];

  //filtering the category
  const categories = priceArray.filter((level) => {
    return level.lowEnd < price && price < level.highEnd;
  });

  ////filtering the restaurants
  restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
    categories.map((category) => {
      if (
        category.lowEnd < restaurant.averagePrice &&
        restaurant.averagePrice < category.highEnd
      ) {
        filteredRestaurants.push(restaurant);
      }
    });
  });

  filteredRestaurants.map((restaurant) => console.log(restaurant.name));
}

showRestaurants(15);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).